# Sort several lists based on first lists order by maximum

Tags: python, list, sorting

How would I sort several other lists on the new order of a list.
Example:

```
lst1=[3,5,1,7]
lst2= [1,2,3,4]
lst3=[100,99,98,97]
lst4 = [20,17,192,309]

list1_set=list(sorted((set(lst1))))
list1_set.reverse()
#gives me lst1=[7,5,3,1]
```

Now I would like the other lists to sort in the same way so that it looks like that:

```
lst2=[4,2,1,3]
lst3=[97,99,100,98]
lst4=[309,17,20,192]
```

Means each item that was at position `n` before is at position `m` afterwards for all the items of all lists. I hope I made it clear, it is not so easy to explain in words. Does someone now how to do that?

Comment: What is the point of `list1_set`? You never use this object anywhere.

Comment: What do you intend to achieve by doing this? We could help better if explained.

Comment: sorry @PMende I edited it. I created it to be able to use the reverse function

Answer (score 4):

Create the relevant indices `idx` and then just use getitem/list comprehensions:

```
>>> idx = sorted(range(len(lst1)), key=lst1.__getitem__, reverse=True)
>>> [lst2[i] for i in idx]
[4, 2, 1, 3]
>>> [lst3[i] for i in idx]
[97, 99, 100, 98]
>>> [lst4[i] for i in idx]
[309, 17, 20, 192]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine

Comment: I like `operator.itemgetter()` ... `order = operator.itemgetter(*idx); order(lst2) --> (4, 2, 1, 3)`.

Comment: @wwii: And `order = lambda lst, getter=operator.itemgetter(*idx): list(getter(lst))` would make it create lists instead of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` all lists together, sort according to the desired list, and then unpack the `zip` to receive the sorted lists:

```
lst1=[3,5,1,7]
lst2=[1,2,3,4]
lst3=[100,99,98,97]
lst4=[20,17,192,309]

lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4 = zip(*sorted(zip(lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Seems to be a very short and nice way to do it @Zohar Meir

Comment: Note: output will be tuples, not lists.  And you **don't actually need the sort key at all** here (default key will do the same).

Comment: Thanks @wim. The output can be converted to lists by mapping each of the output tuples to a list: `map(list, zip(*...))`